# Can any one ID my tortoise?

Tags: species-identification, herpetology

I have got a pet tortoise and I was wondering if any one could identify it. I think it's a male around 2 years old.

I'm not quite sure, it is quite small, very shy and goes very fast.

He likes carrots, pears, apples and tomatoes.

At the bottom of his shell there's sum light orange color.

Basically light line of orange on each side but only on the bottom of his shell.

If this helps at his last owner house he was bitten by a dog and his shell was repaired by a local farmer with fibreglass.

[image][image][image][image]

Comment: For getting more accurate answer I would add some more details like if you found the tortoise in the nature or if you got from another way. Telling which country you're living would also add better match if you found it in the nature. For me it looks like a Hermann's tortoise but as I am not specialist, it could be another one from the `Testudo` family (or even another if yours is not coming from Europe).

Comment: Normally for determining the gender, i think it's the length of the tail which differs. I would add one more picture with the tail fully out. The end of the tail can also detarmine the family / genus of the tortoise.

Comment: Another point about size: `it is quite small` is very subjective and as they grow very slowly, the specimen you shows does not look so small. If you can just put how many Centimeter (or Inch) it is (ideally length, width and high) it would also help other people to have a better estimate.